# JS: Making certain elements of a class hidden via getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, hide, getelementsbyclassname

My code:

```
<div  class="subManuSched'.$data2->ordernumber.'">
<div  class="subManuSched'.$data2->ordernumber.'">
<div  class="subManuSched'.$data2->ordernumber.'">
...onclick="hidediv('.$data2->ordernumber.')...


function hidediv(counter) {   
            document.getElementsByClassName('subManuSched'+counter)[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            alert('subManuSched'+counter);
    }
```

I want to hide several div with the same class-name. With the Code mentioned I don't get an error, but also Nothing happens. $data2->ordernumber is a given Parameter to the JS function, named there "counter". The alert in the end shows me the name of the class correctly, and I've checked it with source code.
I've found solutions here which have worked for others very often, but it never works with my code. Don't know why!

Comment: `...onclick="hidediv('.$data2->ordernumber.')...` <<-- Is this a button which triggers hidediv on click or? Can you post the full line.

Comment: $this->html .= '<td onclick="hidediv('.$data2->ordernumber.');">R</td>';

Comment: When I try wrong code I see an error when "onclick" this element

Comment: It's possible to access the styles with: alert(myClasses[0].style.color);  but it's not possible to set the style

Comment: hm... now it's possible for me to hide the whole table, but my intention is to hide only some row elements of the table! How would this be possible? Currently I've wrapped the tr-element with the div mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please replicate what you have so far in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with 'visibility' when dynamically changing it from JS, you should try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('subManuSched'+counter)[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: no, unfortunately this alos has no effect, but this also does not cause an error

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with that code I've found on stackoverflow:

```
$this->html .= '<tr><td class="toggler" data="'.$data2->AUNR.$data2->Nr.'">P</td>';


    var DELAY = 700, clicks = 0, timer = null;
    $(function(){
        $(".toggler").on("click", function(e){
            clicks++;  //count clicks
            if(clicks === 1) {
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    alert("Single Click");  //perform single-click action    
                    $('.submanusched'+$(this).attr('data')).toggle();
                    clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
                }, DELAY);
            } else {
                clearTimeout(timer);    //prevent single-click action
                alert("Double Click");  //perform double-click action
                $('.submanusched'+$(this).attr('data')).toggle();
                clicks = 0;             //after action performed, reset counter
            }
        })
        .on("dblclick", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
        });
    });
```

,but only the inserted line at "Double Click" is processed! I see both alerts, but the line iserted at "Single Click" is never been processed! 
Do you have an idea why? What's wrong?

Thanks for help!
Stefan